# Recursive function - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, ecmascript-6

Hei guys,

I get confused with a recursive function, it reaches maximum call stack

```
const reversNumber = n => {
    return parseFloat( n.toString().split('').reverse().join('') );
};

const reversAddFunction = (n, count = 1) => {
    const sum = n + reversNumber(n);
    console.log(sum)

    if(sum === reversNumber(sum)){
        return [count, sum];
    } else {
        return reversAddFunction(sum, ++count);
    }
}
console.log(reversAddFunction(196));
```

Any advice how can edit the function to be ok with same result?
Thank you!

Comment: why would you assume this would ever complete? You're not incrementing by 1 every time, you're incrementing by one, then 2 then 3 etc

Comment: What is the goal here?

Comment: why would this be done with recursion?

Comment: Right now you don't have a result, something is wrong. Maximum call stack size exceeded means the function has been called too many times. This usually implies an infinite loop. In your case it looks like a loop that would take long enough to be practically infinite. My advice: think of the math here before going to code it. If you're writing this to work on a math problem, you have an answer that if your result will ever be returned, it will take too long for a javascript to figure out through recursion.

Comment: E.g.: 68
    68 + 86 = 154       // step 1
    154 + 451 = 605     // step 2
    605 + 506 = 1111    // step 3
    => [3, 1111]

i need to stop the function when it founds a number which is the same from the beginning to end and reverse..like 323, 555, 121, also need to return the steps, in how many attempts the operation was done

Comment: So, why not use a loop for this?

Comment: The recursion keeps happening because your test condition `(sum === reversNumber(sum))` is always false.

Comment: So does 196 actually have an answer? Does it get into the realm of a number too big for JavaScript to properly handle?

Comment: I just ran it with BigInts, and there is no solution: the number gets bigger and bigger, and one can see that the more digits the number gets the lower the probability that the base case applies for that number. So the question is: what did you expect as return value and why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason as to why you're function with 196 as an input exceeds the maximum call stack is because your function is called too many times before reaching an answer. In fact, even converting your function to a loop to avoid the maximum call stack error still does not yield an answer for your function with 196 as an input.

See the following:

```js
const reverseNumber = n => {
  return Number(n.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));
};

const reverseAddLoop = n => {
  let currNum = n;
  let count = 1;

  while (true) {
    const sum = currNum + reverseNumber(currNum);

    if (Number.isNaN(sum)) {
      console.log(count, currNum);
      return [-1, -1]
    } else if (sum === reverseNumber(sum)) {
      return [count, sum];
    }

    currNum = sum;
    count += 1;
  }
}

console.log(reverseAddLoop(196))
```

On my machine, `1.000000505374505e+21` is the last computed sum after `114876` iterations before the sum becomes `NaN`, but this is already way wrong because after 35 iterations your sum is already bigger than Javascript's maximum integer value (2^53 - 1) so basically you can discard anything you get after this point.

In this situation, `BigInt` seems particularly useful but even using `BigInt` I failed to reach an answer with 196 as an input after letting it run for 1 minute. See:

```js
const reverseBigInt = n => {
  return BigInt(n.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));
}

const reverseAddBigIntLoop = n => {
  let currNum = n;
  let count = 1;

  while (true) {
    const sum = currNum + reverseBigInt(currNum);

    if (sum === reverseBigInt(sum)) {
      return [count, sum];
    }

    currNum = sum;
    count += 1;
  }
}

console.log(reverseAddBigIntLoop(196n))
```

There probably is not answer for 196, and if there is the answer is way too big for you to compute.